# gevent find parent greenlet

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets, call-hierarchy

Is there a way to know from which greenlet the current greenlet was spawned from in gevent?

1. I realize that the greenlet which spawned the current greenlet might have terminated already, but in that case I would be ok with handling a None as an answer.
2. I am aware of gevent.Greenlet.parent but this represents only the hub, not the direct greenlet from which the current greenlet was started from
3. I would prefer a solution that does not involve monkey patching gevent.Greenlet

My use case is: I have a server which handles requests to execute python code (yes, yes, it is unsafe I know :-). Each request spawns a greenlet which handles the request, including redirecting any input, output or error to a channel private to the request. I want to be able to handle requests concurrently and the requests may spawn greenlets themselves.

You can find an example of what I am trying to do [here](https://github.com/tiagocoutinho/gtools/blob/master/gtools/multistd.py)

Answer (score 0):

In original `greenlet` package, creating new greenlet object has the following signature `greenlet(run=None, parent=None)`. So it means that you can provide `parent` argument or keep it `None` and greenlet assigns caller function by default.

On top of this package, gevent provides tools and tiny event loop that orchestrates greenlets behaviour and [lifecycle](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.hub.html) . So any greenlet that is created by `gevent.spawn`  or `gevent.Greenlet` automatically inherits current hub (event loop) as a parent. So every time when one greenlet finishes its execution, it transfer control back to event loop. According to documentation: "This allows a greenlet to take some cleanup actions before yielding control."

However, looking in documentation and [source code](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/greenlet.py#L131) of Greenlet initialization, I see that is still possible to override constructor by providing new arguments.

```
from gevent.greenlet import Greenlet as GeventGreenlet


class Greenlet(GeventGreenlet):

    def __init__(self, caller=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Greenlet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._caller = caller
```

Then you need to tell greenlet package to use your Greenlet implementation (similar to gevent monkeypatch) as early as possible.

```
import gevent.greenlet
from myapp.greenlet import Greenlet

gevent.greenlet.Greenlet = Greenlet
```

Comment: I am already avoiding to use gevent monkey patching so I would prefer a solution that does not involve monkey patching gevent itself